# Show error everytime i install scipy module in python2.7

Tags: python

I'm using 32-bit Python. Whenever I install Scipy (scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win32.whl from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)) module in Python 2.7 using `pip`, I got this error:

[image]

```
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
corpus = [[(0, 1.0), (1, 1.0), (2, 1.0)],
     [(2, 1.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 1.0), (5, 1.0), (6, 1.0), (8, 1.0)],
     [(1, 1.0), (3, 1.0), (4, 1.0), (7, 1.0)]]
```

Why this is failing and how can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install gensim` ? Since you are getting an "ImportError: No module named gensim"...

Comment: yeah i installed gensim but still i'm getting this error